# Filtrar um select, sem que sejam retornado consultas duplicadas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

O problema consiste em retornar um SELECT com somente os agendamentos que já não tenham sido aceitos pelo usuário. Estou tentando usar a tabela de agendamentos que já foram aceitos, que possuem tanto o ID do usuário quanto do agendamento que ele aceitou para filtrar os agendamento.

**Tabela de agendamentos aceitos**

```
| SCHEDULE_ID |   USER_ID    |
------------------------------
      25      |      26      |
      41      |      26      |
      41      |      26      |
      42      |      29      |
```

As chaves vem da ligação da tabela com as seguintes tabelas:

**Tabela de agendamentos criados**

```
SCHEDULE_ID |    TITULO    |  DAILY_PRICE  |  CLIENT_ID  |
----------------------------------------------------------
 41         |  Padaria     |    290.00     |      1      |
 42         |  Confeitaria |    350.00     |      2      |
 25         |  Lavanderia  |    350.00     |      3      |
```

**Tabela de entregadores Registrados**

```
 USER_ID    |    NAME    |
--------------------------
 25         |   João     |
 26         |   Maria    |
 29         |   Claúdio  |
```

Não tenho muito costume com o uso de instruções SQL ainda, então não consegui desenvolver um query que retornasse os valores, sem que estes viessem repetidos por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para chegar ao resultado desejado você deve utilizar a cláusula `EXISTS` em conjunto com `NOT`:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM agendamentos a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM agendamento_aceitos aa
                   WHERE aa.schedule_id = a.schedule_id
                     AND aa.user_id = 26)
```

No exemplo acima serão mostrados agendamentos que ainda não foram aceitos pelo entregador 26 - Maria.

---

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a subquery retornar qualquer linha, EXISTS será VERDADEIRO, e NOT EXISTS será FALSO

Comment: Acho que esse é o caminho, filtra agendamentos não retornando aqueles que já foram alguma vez aceitos. No entanto é esperado que ele retornasse agendamentos apenas que não foram aceitos pelo próprio usuário ainda, usando ai a tabela que registra agendamentos aceitos pelos usuários entregadores.

Comment: @wagnermps você quer os entregadores que aceitaram agendamentos? Isso?

Comment: A ideia desse select seria mostrar ao entregador agendamentos novos que foram criados e estão na tabela de agendamentos, quando ele decide aceitar um desses agendamentos um insert é feito em agendamentos_aceitos, mas mesmo depois que esse entregador aceita esse agendamento, esse agendamento ainda permanece disponível pra que outros entregadores também aceitem no futuro.

Comment: Agora, quando esse mesmo usuário(entregador) que aceitou esse agendamento de antes quiser ver os novos agendamentos, a query precisaria filtrar com base no id dele aqueles agendamentos que ainda não foram aceitos somente por ele, podendo retornar agendamentos que foram aceitos por outros entregadores sem problema.

Comment: @wagnermps entendi, então é só adicionar o `user_id` no `WHERE` da `subquery`. Fiz a alteração na resposta referente a isso

Comment: show resolvido, quando usei sua resposta antes removi o aa.schedule_id = a.schedule_id por aa.user_id = 26, quando o correto era usar os dois obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve realizar um join, o join junta os resultados de duas tabelas em uma so consulta, ele utiliza de um campo para realizar esta junção.

**Exemplo de junção desejada**

```
Select Entregadores.NAME,
       Agendamento.TITULO,
       Agendamento.DAILY_PRICE,
       Agendamento.CLIENT_ID 
  from Tabela_de_agendamentos_que_foram_aceitos AgendamentoAceito
   join Tabela_de_agendamentos_criados Agendamento
     on (AgendamentoAceito.SCHEDULE_ID = Agendamento.SCHEDULE_ID)
   join Tabela_de_entregadores_que_aceitaram_os_agendamentos Entregadores
     on (AgendamentoAceito.USER_ID = Entregadores.USER_ID)
```

Com todos os join bem posicionados os registros não vão se repetir, ao menos que se repitam nas tabelas.

**Falando um pouco mais de join**

Muitos desenvolvedores têm a dificuldade de saber qual resultado é retornado por cada join no SQL e, portanto, quando devem utilizar cada um. Para facilitar esse entendimento, a Figura 1 traz uma representação gráfica, baseada na Teoria dos Conjuntos, muito conhecida na matemática. Nessa imagem, temos a representação de duas tabelas (A e B) e o resultado esperado por cada tipo de join (a área em vermelho representa os registros retornados pela consulta).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006

Comment: É ai que se encontra minha dúvida, mais de um usuário pode aceitar um determinado agendamento. E estou atrás de uma query que retorne os agendamentos que Não foram aceitos pelo usuário, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Esta query minha resolveu o seu problema inicial? Confere para mim que ae nos trabalhamos em uma segunda.

Answer (score -2):

Pode usar um `distinct` na query de forma a retornar valores únicos.

Comment: Você poderia dar um exemplo? Se não acredito que sua resposta caiba melhor como comentário.

Comment: Verifique aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp